# Can I use executorservice to kill a specific thread if it's been running for too long?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt, executor

So far in my experiments with the executorservice I've had a lot of advice that involves using future.get, and then future.cancel in order to throw a thread interrupt which then needs to be caught in the thread, and handled there.    My question is a little different.

Assuming that I was running a thread that simply kept track of how long things were running and if they passed by some threshold, would this be a good way to kill the executorservice and all running threads?

Example thought process:

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(12);
timekeeper.start();
List<Future<?>> taskList = new ArrayList<Future<?>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < objectArray.length; i++) {
        Future<?> task = threadPool.submit(new ThreadHandler(objectArray[i], i));
        taskList.add(task);
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }

if(timekeeper.now() > 60)
    threadpool.shutdownNow();
}
```

Would this work?   I have no way to check since my threads fail extremely infrequently (about 1/700 runs, and only at certain hours of the day when I'm not working).

Comment: The most effective method to kill I know is the .stop() method, is deprecated but it still works

Comment: As of Java 18, `Thread.stop()` is marked as deprecated **for removal in a future version**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `shutdownNow` method attempts to interrupt all of active task threads, and this would only work if the tasks were coded to respected interrupts.  They would need to:

- check to see if the interrupt flag has been set in long running loops, and
- deal with `InterruptedException`s correctly.

Basically the tasks needs to cooperate for interrupts to work.  If they don't cooperate, there is no safe and reliable way to stop them ... apart from exiting the JVM.

---

> Above someone mentioned the .stop() method as a comment, can you provide commentary as to why this would be a bad idea?

The [`Thread.stop()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28%29) method is [deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) because it is fundamentally unsafe.  Stopping a thread can leave critical data structures in an intermediate state, and can interfere with other threads that were interacting with it in various ways.  It is theoretically possible to use `stop` safely, but it is difficult to work out a set of general preconditions that are sufficient to ensure that nothing bad happens.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I would do

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(12);
List<Future<?>> taskList = new ArrayList<Future<?>>();
for (int i = 0; i < objectArray.length; i++) {
    taskList.add(threadPool.submit(new ThreadHandler(objectArray[i], i)));
threadPool.shutdown();
threadPool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // or what ever
threadPool.shutdownNow();
```

This assumes your tasks will honour interrupts.  If they do not there is no clean way to kill a thread (except using a flag which is much the same thing)

---

Reasons not to use Thread.stop() here

- You don't have access to the Thread objects to call stop() on.
- If a task is ignores interrupt() it is likely to be poorly behaved, which can leave the heap in a corrupt state.
- Calling stop() should stop the task but won't stop a thread pool thread unless it has been `shutdown()` as it traps it. (Admittedly, easy to work around)

Comment: Above someone mentioned the .stop() method as a comment, can you provide commentary as to why this would be a bad idea?

Comment: @A_Elric - See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html.  And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504140. Also note that as of Java 18 it is now marked as deprecated **for removal in a future version**.

Comment: @StephenC also Thread.stop(Throwable) throws an Exception for the caller since Java 9.

Comment: @StephenC Dedication coming back to such an old question, but it's still relevant today.