# Thread methods deprecated

Tags: java, multithreading

When am trying to stop a running thread, most of  the methods to stop the thread are being shown "deprecated" in eclipse. I am using either of the methods stop(),destroy(),suspend(). Is there a new method for stopping a thread?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the sample code that you are trying? use a `flag` as boolean to come out of `run` method. If run method is finished then thread is automatically closed. Rest depends on your code.

Comment: Because these methods are deprecated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16504140/1927832

Comment: It is deprecated because it was bad. IIRC the new recommendation is to do periodic polling and have the thread stop itself by cleaning up and then returning from the run method.

Comment: @ColinD---Well the question which you people have referred has only subpart of answer.Kindly open the question to be answered,else it will be considered monopoly of `higher rated professionals` on Stack Overflow!

Comment: @shekharsuman, I do not agree with you. I believe that everything that the OP may want to know is in the other question.

Comment: @shekharsuman I clearly think it is a duplicate of the one it is marked a duplicate as. The first answer looks like it provides a reason for deprecation and a solution for 'stopping'. If you disagree, the question linked by suresh, would be another likely candidate for being a duplicate. Stackoverflow has no need for duplicates, why would we ever re-open a question just for the sake of fake internet points? We are simply a site about providing answers for questions, re-answering questions just clutters the site.