# Thread doesn't stop on calling stopService() in MainActivity

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Context c=this;
Intent i;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v)
        {
        i=new Intent(c,serv.class);
        startService(i);
        }
    });

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            stopService(i);

        }
    });
}
}
```

Serv

```
class bob implements Runnable{
Thread ac;

public void run() 
{
    while(true)
    {
        Log.d("tag","RUNNING");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}   }
public class serv extends Service {
Thread ac;


public void onCreate() {
        Log.d("tag","CREATED");
        super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d("tag","SERVICE STARTED");

    ac=new Thread(new bob());
    ac.start();


    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d("tag","DESTROYED");
try{
    ac.stop();
}catch(Exception e)
{e.printStackTrace();}


}

public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

}
```

When I click on the button to StopService, the ondestroy() message is called but my thread keeps on running.
Log is given below:

> 03-26 16:48:45.065: D/tag(15674): CREATED
>
> 03-26 16:48:45.065: D/tag(15674): SERVICE STARTED
>
> 03-26 16:48:45.065: D/tag(15674): RUNNING
>
> 03-26 16:48:45.495: D/tag(15674): RUNNING
>
> 03-26 16:48:46.065: D/tag(15674): RUNNING
>
> 03-26 16:48:46.495: D/tag(15674): RUNNING
>
> 03-26 16:48:47.065: D/tag(15674): RUNNING
>
> 03-26 16:48:47.495: D/tag(15674): RUNNING
>
> 03-26 16:48:48.065: D/tag(15674): RUNNING
>
> 03-26 16:48:48.505: D/tag(15674): RUNNING
>
> 03-26 16:48:48.615: D/tag(15674): DESTROYED
>
> 03-26 16:48:49.065: D/tag(15674): RUNNING
>
> 03-26 16:48:49.495: D/tag(15674): RUNNING

Comment: Look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961714/how-to-properly-stop-the-thread-in-java

Comment: You are creating a new thread inside your service you are not stopping .. so it will be running

Comment: @PreethiRao i am stopping it in onDestroy()

Comment: you are not supposed to use Thread.stop() it is deprecated ..

Comment: @PreethiRao so what should i use?

Comment: @AlexKlimashevsky Thank you it worked, but i still would like to know why i was not able to stop the thread using Thread.stop()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504140/thread-stop-deprecated to know more about Thread.stop().

Answer (score 0):

try this out ..

```
class bob implements Runnable{
Thread ac;
boolean isRunning = true;
public void run() 
{
    while(isRunning)
    {
        Log.d("tag","RUNNING");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

} 
 public void stopRunning()
{
isRunning = false;
 }
```

And in your service have a reference to the runnable object and call stopRunning() method...

Comment: I found a more efficient solution, Still Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The code suggests some share variables problems. This code uses references in a non-appropriate way.  For example, `ac=new Thread(new bob())` uses a new instance reference for bob() class but does not control it on `while(true){…}` loop. In addition, to use a `while(true)` or `while(1==1)` is a bad practice because this can crash all the application. [See for example on GitHub](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=while%28true%29&type=Code&ref=searchresults). These are very bad codes that could produce unexpected things.

I re-work your example using a semaphore approach. In this case, I define a `private Boolean semaphore` variable that controls the access to the while loop.

It is very important to notice that the access to `run()` method is performed by `isAlive()` method, it also is used to check if the there is no more to do on destroyng action.

The code re-worked uses the natural monitor control existing on JVM. In this case, recommended from the [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28%29)

> **Thread.stop() - Deprecated**. This method is inherently unsafe. Stopping a thread with Thread.stop causes it to unlock all of the monitors that it has locked [...]. Many uses of  the stop should be replaced by code that simply modifies some variable to indicate that the target thread should stop running. [...]

This approach can be easily adapted to Android or others Java environments.

---

```
class MainActivity{
    private Service service;
    public MainActivity(){
        service = new Service();
    }
    public void startService(){
        service.onCreate();
        service.onStartCommand();
    }
    public void stopService(){
        service.onDestroy();

    }
}

class Bob implements Runnable{
    private Boolean semaphore;
    public Bob(){
        this.semaphore = Boolean.FALSE;
    }

    public void active(){
        this.semaphore = Boolean.TRUE;
    }

    public void deactivate(){
        this.semaphore = Boolean.FALSE;
    }

    public Boolean isAlive(){
        return this.semaphore;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while( isAlive() ){
            System.out.println("RUNNING");
            sleep();
        }
    }

    private void sleep() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
class Service{
    private static final int START_NOT_STICKY = 1;
    private Thread sThread;
    private Bob rBob;

    public Service(){
        this.rBob    = new Bob();
        this.sThread = new Thread( rBob );
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        System.out.println("CREATED");
    }

    public int onStartCommand() {
        System.out.println("SERVICE STARTED");

        rBob.active();
        sThread.start();

        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        rBob.deactivate();
        if( sThread.isAlive() && !rBob.isAlive() ) {
            System.out.println("DESTROYED");
        }
    }
}
public class SampleThreadTest {

    public static void main(String a[]) throws InterruptedException {
        MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();

        Thread.sleep(1000);
            ma.startService();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
            ma.stopService();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```