# Interrupting long working thread

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, interrupt

I am trying to interrupt thread that is working long. In my example inside run() method appear lots of different method with take quite a lot of time (e.g writing into database). I would like to stop (kill) that thread from another one. I have seen solution like:

```
while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
    try{
        // do stuff
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // propagate interrupt
    }
}
```

but I've got no while loop inside my code. Can anyone help me to deal with that?

---

Here's the code:

```
public void run() //parsingThread
    {
        try {
            for(int index=0; index<tasks.size();)
            { //do sth
                if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()==true)
                {       
                    System.out.println("Parsing ABORTED");
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();             
                }               
            }


            for(int index=0; index<1000;index++)
            {   //do sth  
                if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()==true)
                {
                    System.out.println("Parsing ABORTED");
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }}
```

Comment: You already seem to know what you need to do. You haven't posted any of your own code so it's difficult to see why you're expecting from us.

Comment: If you want to kill a thread from another thread call `thread.interrupt()` where `thread` is the long working thread. Don't use `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` That's like interrupting yourself.

Comment: @AbishekManoharan, OP never suggested interrupting the current thread. I think you misread the question.

Comment: In general, it's good practice to put the try/catch around your while loop, instead of inside it.  That way, an interrupt will automatically terminate the loop.

Comment: @Hobo Sapiens I've inserted code in post below.

Answer (score 4):

If your long-running database calls don't respond to interrupts, then you're basically out of luck, and need to resort to workarounds if you for instance want a responsive user interface.

One way is to run the database methods in a background thread and periodically check for stop-early conditions (such as interruptions) in the main thread. When such condition is discovered, you simply abandon the background thread and ignore any future results from it.

If possible, you could try to split up the long running task into multiple smaller tasks, and check for interrupts in between.

(Some people may point you to [`Thread.stop`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28%29), but that method has been deprecated [for very good reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504140/thread-stop-deprecated).)

Official documentation (which in part answers the question you posted too):

[Why Are `Thread.stop`, `Thread.suspend`,
`Thread.resume` and `Runtime.runFinalizersOnExit` Deprecated?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)

---

Regarding your code.

If `//do sth` is a long running task, the `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()==true` check is never executed.

I've copied your program and executed it locally, and the `"Parsing ABORTED"` is being printed for me.

Comment: I don’t understand, how adding `index++` ought to make a difference. The loop’s body containing the check is executed, regardless of whether `index++` is present or not. The lack of `index++` makes the loop infinite but doesn’t change the interruption behavior.

Comment: Hmm. You're absolutely right. I thought it was an unreachability issue, but it's obviously not. Deleting this from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up two entirely different things. Code fragments containing statements like `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` are *not* handling interrupts as said statement is for *restoring* the interrupt status so that callers may handle it.

Since you want to handle the interrupting, that is not the right thing. If you detect an interruption, you just need a simple statement telling the compiler what to do. So if you want your task to return upon interruption, just use a statement as simple as

```
if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    // if you need cleanup, do it here
    return;
}
```

Generally, don’t copy code from somewhere else whose purpose you don’t understand.

Comment: But as I mention the problem is with detecting isInterrupted() inside loop in code below.

Comment: Add an `else` statement to check whether you even encounter the check. If your code is blocked somewhere else, the check can’t help. If the check is executed but evaluates to `false`, well, then you haven’t interrupted the thread, but maybe some other thread…