# Unreachable catch block for InterruptedException and Class.newInstance()

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt, interrupt-handling, interrupted-exception

In a current project, I am attempting to load a set of plugins; The problem is that plugin could do anything, include throwing exceptions, or just hanging forever. I am trying to accomplish the following:

```
try {

    // load class by package name
    Class<?> pluginClass = Class.forName(plginClassName);

    // create a new instance of the object
    // this call could throw an exception or never return
    GenericPlugin plugin = (GenericPlugin) pluginClass.newInstance();

    state = PluginState.INITIALIZED;
    ...

} catch ( InterruptedException ie ) {  // <-- Compile Error Here
// Unreachable catch block for InterruptedException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body

    state = PluginState.TIMEOUT;
} catch ( Exception ex ) {

    state = PluginState.FAILED;
}
```

I would like it such that in my calling class of the loader thread I can do:

```
LoaderThread t = new LoaderThread( pluginClassName );

// start loading the plugin
t.start();

// wait 5 seconds for startup
t.join( 5000 );

// interrupt if not complete
t.interrupt();

// get my plugin state
pluginState = t.getPluginState();
```

If i am going at this wrong, please advise, but

> How can I timeout a call to `class.newInstance()`?

Comment: You can only catch `InterruptedException` from a method that explicitly throws it. Usually that's the case for methods that are meant to block, like concurrent utilities or I/O. Otherwise, you'll need to check for interrupted state manually (`Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted()`). If the code that's hanging is out of your control, the best you can do is try to interrupt and hope someone in there is listening.

Comment: I've changed up the actual question slightly, would there be any way of simply timing out the call to `newInstance()`?

Comment: Your code already times out by calling `t.join(5000)`. But can't safely *kill* a thread without its cooperation. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504140/thread-stop-deprecated