# Stop Thread Runnable impossible

Tags: android, multithreading, runnable

I have this thread:

```
myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        ServerSocket ss = null;

                        while (!end) {

                            final String incomingMsg;
                            try {
                                ss = new ServerSocket(2201);
                                ss.setSoTimeout(15000);
.. some code ...
    }
                });
                myThread.start();
```

Now i need to stop this with button but nothing work, and i have tried with some code like:

```
Handler handler= new Handler();
handler.removeCallbacks(myThread);
myThread.interrupt();
```

But Thread not stopping =(

Comment: myThread.stop(); doesn't work??

Comment: .Stop is obsolete and not work =(

Comment: Why don't you change the value of your 'end' variable?  end = true;

Comment: Great idea, thank you, but I would also like to see if there are different methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted answer is not correct. Android does nothing to manage the threads you start, however you start them.

Technically speaking, threads cannot be "stopped". They can interrupted. Interrupting a thread just means that a flag is set, which you, in your thread's implementation, need to consider and exit from the `run()` method. For example,

```
  Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        // Do stuff
      }
    }
  });
```

Then you can call `t.interrupt()` later on to "stop" your thread.

If you ignore the interrupted flag in your thread's implementation, your thread will never stop. For example, if you replaced `// Do stuff` above with `SystemClock.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE)` the thread will never exit, regardless of it being interrupted.

Many IO operations implemented in the SDK also pay attention to the interrupted flag, which is why you can interrupt a thread that's participating in blocking IO. See `InterruptedException`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Android will automatically stops thread when needed.

What you can do is just stop executing the code inside `run()` method, Using `boolean` or something

Comment: This answer is not correct. Android does nothing to manage the threads you start, however you start them. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .stop(), but it is very bad practice and it can cause you some troubles. Try to add some boolean inside your .run() (like Wizard said)

Comment: .stop is deprecated =)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504140/thread-stop-deprecated

Comment: My bad. I haven't used .stop() quite a lot of time. Good luck finding working solution.