# Python threads, stopping/starting/killing

Tags: python, python-multithreading

In Python's documentation (v3.8.2) on threading, there is this text (ch. 17): "Python’s Thread class supports a subset of the behavior of Java’s Thread class; currently, there are no priorities, no thread groups, and threads cannot be destroyed, stopped, suspended, resumed, or interrupted." I haven't been hampered by no means of prioritizing, or grouping threads, but that last bit, "cannot be destroyed, stopped, suspended, resumed, or interrupted" is an issue.

I have an application that starts one thread to post sensor-data to a queue, and another one to pull sensor data from that queue, then post it to a curses window. The trouble is, there are instances where thread pairs (they're always pairs in this case) get over-written with new threads, owing to configuration changes, etc. Until now, I have been deleting the thread objects under the foolish assumption that this action will result in the destruction of said threads. I have noticed some weird behaviour in the app, which now makes sense, as several threads are attempting to post data to the same curses window object.

Changing my approach, I will create several thread pairs, treat them as indestructible, update their configurations as needed... but how do I control their execution from the main thread? Is there a best practice? I'm thinking, create several pairs of template threads, start them, and use the threading.Condition() or the threading.Event() class to start/stop the code inside each thread running, but how do I pass information about what to do to each running thread? Since I have not done this, I'm learning mostly by the time-honoured tradition of rtfm; but, examples and a little guidance will help. Do I use threading.Event.is_set()? If so, how do I set/clear the internal flag from outside the thread? Are threading.Event() objects global, and hence visible to the threads, or do I need to make the Event() object one of the arguments of the function executed by the thread, then let the thread function evaluate the Event() and set/clear it in the main thread?

Comment: Read [Understand threading in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of the unsupported operations, it’s only interrupt that you *should* want; Java has long deprecated the others as being [impossible to use safely in general](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16504140/8586227).  Since Python lacks even the generic interrupt interface (except that an interrupt produces a `KeyboardInterrupt` on the *main* thread only, which is not very useful), you have to avoid basic functions like [`time.sleep`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49877671/8586227) in favor of versions that also detect an inter-thread signal.  (In general, successful methods of *killing* a thread are also able to *control* it, since they involve getting the thread’s attention and then having *it* exit.)

Details:

- Dropping references to a `Thread` object can’t kill it: threads are the **roots** for garbage collection.
- **All** objects are shared between threads: that’s what distinguishes them from processes.  (That’s not to say that threads typically *use* their theoretical access to a large number of objects, nor to say that they shouldn’t *minimize* the number of shared objects for simplicity.)
- Libraries that you call may or may not provide an interface to interrupt their long-running operations; for example, some will gracefully return control to you upon receipt of an “ignored” signal like `SIGPIPE`.

Comment: Thanks, that helped; the java note is illuminating too. So, if a thread completes, does this mean its resources are still assigned, but it is no longer on the list of threads to switch in & out? Meaning, it exists until the python interpreter exits or the main thread completes?

Comment: @stderr: No, a thread’s resources are released when it finishes (*i.e.*, returns from the function you specified for it to execute), with perhaps a small amount surviving until another thread **joins** it (or the whole process exits).  The main thread has nothing to do with it.