# A question regarding an error when processing a java with multithreads?

Tags: multithreading

Please help me figure out what when wrong in this coding.

```js
import java.lang.Thread;

class MyThread1 extends Thread
{ public void run()
{    for(int x=1;x<=15;x++)
  {  if(x==10)
   { stop();
    }
System.out.println(x);
}
}
}
class MyMain
{ public static void main(String args[])
{ MyThread1 first_thread=new MyThread1();
first_thread.start();
}
}
```

the error is
Note: MyClass.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Comment: We no longer stop threads.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504140/thread-stop-deprecated

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you should not call `Thread.stop()`.  It is deprecated and dangerous.

Read [Thread.stop() - deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504140/thread-stop-deprecated) to find out why `stop()` is deprecated.  Or the javadoc.

If you want the thread to terminate itself, it can simply return from the `run()` method:

```
public void run() { 
    for (int x = 1; x <= 15; x++) {  
        if (x == 10) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

or throw an unchecked exception:

```
public void run() { 
    for (int x = 1; x <= 15; x++) {  
        if (x == 10) {
            throw new RuntimeException("It is 10am and your pants are on fire!");
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, you should choose a more appropriate exception and message ...